# updating all files on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I'm trying to determine the "best" way for a small company to keep web app EC2 instances in sync with current files while using autoscaling.

From my research, CloudFormation, Chef, Puppet, OpsWorks, and others seem like the tools to do so. All of them seem to have a decent learning curve, so I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction and I'll learn one.

The initial setup I am after is:

- Route53
- 1x Load Balancer
- 2x EC2 (different AZ) - Apache/PHP
- 1x ElastiCache Redis
- 2x EC2 (different AZ) w/ MySQL
- Email thru Google Apps
- Customer File/Image Storage via S3
- CloudFront for CDN

The only major challenge I can see is versioning/syncing the web/app server. We're small now, so I could probably just manually update the EBS or even using rsync, but I would rather automate it and be setup for autoscaling.

Comment: Have you looked at http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/.  It provides a easy-to-use service for deploying and scaling web applications and services

Comment: Do I have control over the OS and stuff? If I need to update OpenSSL and deploy that update to all servers, I can do that? Or I fix a major bug in PHP, I can update all the files on instances currently running and future instances as well?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably too broad of a question and may be closed, but let me give you a few thoughts.

- Why not use RDS for MySQL?
- You need to get into the thought of how to make and promote disk images.  In the cloud world, you don't want to be `rsync`ing around a bunch of files from server to server.  When you are ready to publish a revised set of code, just make am image from your staging environment, start new EC2 instances in your ELB based on that image, and turn off old instances.  You may have a little different deployment sequence if you need to coordinate with DB schema changes, but that is a pretty straightforward approach.
- You should still seek to automate some of your activities using tools such as those you mentioned. You don't need to do this all at once. Just figure out a manual part in your process that you want to automate and do it.

Comment: I know this already. I just don't know what the best way is to go about automating it. Beanstalk looks the easiest, but I don't know how much control I have. Can I update the OS? Can I update apache, iptables, etc. and push to all instances that need it? Then new instances will also launch with the new updates? Obviously I wouldn't want all my EC2 instances to get all the updates since I am running different instances for different things (like MySQL). I am not using RDS because its 10x slower and replication is easy to setup. I may use Percona/Galera eventually. It's also more expensive.

Comment: @CalebPitman You are really getting into configuration manangement here.  I typically have used a base AMI which contains server-level configurations including Apache configs, etc.  If I need to make changes at this level (i.e. Apache, package updates, etc.) I manage them on this base AMI. I would then deploy application builds on top of this to make application-base AMI's. The are probably hundreds of ways to do this, each with their own pros/cons. Why do you think RDS is 10x slower? Based on what metrics? Were you using right instance types, etc. Now if you go custom MySQL you can't use RDS.

Comment: @CalebPitman But, I would be shocked to that a typical RDS instance that is correctly provisioned for the needs of an application would be 10X slower than MySQL installed on EC2 (thus needing to use slower EBS-backed storage for persistence).  You typically don't need to think about configuring iptables or other host-level firewalls, as you would use AWS security group configurations for this.

Comment: With a 2-3GB DB and 5-7m rows, the full database import alone on RDS couldnt finish with 1k reserved IOPS (which is $100/mo extra). The EC2 instance with EBS General SSD finished in about 10-15 minutes. On both cases I used xlarge instances. I tested "as is" and then I tested after configuring my.cnf. I ran dozens of different queries against a 5m row table and RDS was always 10x slower (the query itself; no latency involved). RDS still is fast (.08 second) but compared to .008 or .0008 that's a huge difference). Paying more money for RDS just to have "easy" replication seems like a waste.

Comment: I see AWS CodeDeploy seems perfect for updating code, but I also need to manage server software. If I need to update a web application firewall, apache configuration, install an intrusion detection system, or upgade form CentOS 6.4 to 6.5, I don't really want to manually create an AMI and then manually launch 10 instances of it. Maybe that's the easiest way to do it though.... for now. I think CloudFormation is meant to do this, but it's not clear without spending a lot of time looking into it.

Comment: @CalebPitman Well certainly application performance has to be weighed out. RDS is not just about replication though, it is also about high availability (multi-AZ instances, more stringent SLA's around internal AWS support for RDS over say EC2, etc.), and easily to automate snapshot capabilities (incremental snapshots, cross-region snapshot sharing, etc.) to where you should not have to do a bunch of full data import/export operations.

Comment: @CalebPitman Most of the tools you mention can automate the creation of a base AMI, application of shell scripts to update packages, change configurations, etc. and then create a new AMI.